# Different speeds on the same Airport Extreme

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, airport

I have a 200 MBs Internet plan connected to my Airport Extreme. Using two different iPads I get 200 MBs in one and in the other 5 feet away 1.2 MBs. The same happened with two MacBooks.

Do you know why this can happen?

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact model of that slower iPad?
Is the speed, when measured, always slower on that other iPad?

The same questions go for MacBooks.

As if one some of them are older models with Wi-Fi chips that do not support that bandwidth. Are you in a position to test this with on MacBooks using the ethernet cable?